# What does it mean by NULL geometry of a shapefile in ArcGIS?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.5, null-geometry

I was trying to work on a line shapefile and while trying to call the firstpoint of the shapefile, it was throwing me an error saying the shapefile has nothing called firstpoint. Then I repaired the geometry using the ArcGIS tool and it got fixed. But, I want to know, what did that mean by repairing the geometry of the shapefile.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm

Comment: Sometimes shapefiles or feature classes have records in the attribute table that do not have any spatial/geometry data associated w/ them. The repair geometry tool will find these and delete them. Also see https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/data-reviewer/data-management/invalid-geometry-check-explained/?rmedium=blogs_esri_com&rsource=/esri/arcgis/2012/03/28/invalid-geometry-check-explained/

Comment: Thank you @Nick. That helped.

Comment: Note that "repair" isn't possible for a null geometry -- The Repair Geometry utility also gives the option to delete null shapes.

Answer (score 1):

NULL shapes are explained in the shapefile specification 
https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

> **Null Shapes**
>
> A shape type of 0 indicates a null shape, with no geometric data for
>   the shape.  Eachfeature type (point, line, polygon, etc.) supports
>   nulls?it is valid to have points and nullpoints in the same shapefile.
>   Often null shapes are place holders; they are used duringshapefile
>   creation and are populated with geometric data soon after they are
>   created.